# Letting a container know its exposed ports in Docker

Tags: docker

Let's say I start a container, exposing a random port to 80 like this: `docker run -d -p 80 -name my_container username/container`.

Is there any way to tell `my_container` on which host's port his 80 was exposed?

**Edit**: My situation:

I'm running Apache to serve some static HTML files, and an Go API server on this container. I'm exposing both services here. The static files request data from the server via javascript on the user's browser, but to be able to do this, the clients need to know on which port the API server is made available, to be able to connect to it. Is this the appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there exists an easy to tell *from the container* the host port on which its port 80 was exposed, but I also believe there is a good reason for that: making the container dependent on this would make it dependent on its containing environment, which goes against Docker's logic.

If you really need this, you could pass the host port as an environment variable to the container using the `-e` flag (assuming that the host port is fixed), or rely on a hack such as mounting the Docker socket *in* the container (`-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`) and have it "inspect himself" (which is similar to what [`progrium/ambassadord`](https://github.com/progrium/ambassadord/blob/master/omni.go#L65) does to implement its *omni* mode).

Maybe you should clarify why you need this information in the first place and perhaps there's a simpler solution that can help you achieve that.

Comment: Is there a particular reason not to use a fixed port for the Go API server (such as `-p 1234:1234` and have your static content use that)?

Comment: None at all, but would like to take advantage of this project to learn how to do it the "Docker way".

Comment: Alright I see! Then I have no better idea, which doesn't mean there isn't :-) The only thing that could be considered a better habit is to dedicate each container to a process, so separate the Apache from the golang API.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `docker ps` which will show the ports, for example

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                   NAMES
containerid         ubuntu:14.04        /bin/bash           14 seconds ago      Up 13 seconds       0.0.0.0:49153->80/tcp   my_container
```

In this instance it is 49153.

Also `docker inspect` will tell you lots about your container, including the port mappings

```
$ docker inspect my_container | grep HostPort
"HostPort": "49153"
```